python: NON-pipadmin user gets ModuleNotFoundError after pipadmin installs ipython
Not a question, sharing something that worked for me:
Two linux users, both in the same "programmers" linux group.
1st user is pipadmin, and does "pip install ipython" to a local PYTHONUSERBASE.
2nd user referencing pipadmin's local PYTHONUSERBASE tries to run ipython (with PYTHONUSERBASE correctly set) and gets the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pipadmin/local/pythonbase/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'


sharing something that worked for me - this is encouraged on this site, but you should do this the following way: phrase your problem (everything before "solution" in your post) as your question and then post the solution as an answer which you accept

Changes made, thank you very much. It looks like I will need to wait until tomorrow before I can accept my own answer.. I'll try that. Thanks again for the guidance.

Solution: pipadmin needs run to the following:
chmod 750 /home/pipadmin/local/pythonbase/lib/python3.8/site-packages

Could not find this solution anywhere here.
Using venv would solve this problem a different way but then make each programmer their own environment administrator AFAIK.
Also, the fact that stackoverflow tag PYTHONUSERBASE doesn't exist suggests most don't opt to install this way.
